# The right API/scrape method to extract tables from a Qlikview app

Tags: python, web-scraping, qlikview

I'm trying to get some tables with specific filters on this qlikview page, for future analysis: http://transferenciasabertas.planejamento.gov.br/QvAJAXZfc/opendoc.htm?document=painelcidadao.qvw&lang=en-US&host=QVS%40srvbsaiasprd01&anonymous=true

I don't want to do it manually (downloading tables for every filter). Therefore, I searched for API's for Python on qlikview website, but only found qliksense API's for SSE (like this https://github.com/qlik-oss/server-side-extension).

Is there any chance that I could automate the retrieving process that I explained using Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server side extensions are used for something else. They extend Qlik's functionality to process data (for example running some statistical functions on top of the displayed data if such functions do not exists in Qlik natively)

Interestingly is that the portal link (http://transferenciasabertas.planejamento.gov.br) is a QlikView app that later redirects to a Qlik Sense app(s). It seems that anonymous users are allowed on the platform (which makes automating data retrieval easier).

Qlik Sense communicates with the browser via web sockets. So the answer to your question is - yes. You can used Python to connect to the underlying Qlik Sense Engine and make some selections and get the data back.

The not very good news is that I dont think there is dedicated Python library so you'll have to send the raw web socket requests by yourself. The documentation for the Engine API can be found at Qlik's [help site](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/November2020/Subsystems/EngineAPI/Content/Sense_EngineAPI/introducing-engine-API.htm)

If you are open for JS solution then you can use Qlik's [enigma.js](https://github.com/qlik-oss/enigma.js/) library for Engine communication.

The web sockets traffic can be monitored from the browser (to view what data is being send/received and its format)

[image: websockets-traffic]