# How to scrape QlikView tables using Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

This Brazilian government [website](https://paineis.cnj.jus.br/QvAJAXZfc/opendoc.htm?document=qvw_l%2FPainelCNJ.qvw&host=QVS%40neodimio03&anonymous=true&sheet=shPORT63Relatorios) features wage data for judges from various instances and courts. I would like to download all the tables, but the data referring to the tables are not in the html that I get as a response when I use `request`.

To work around this issue, I used `puppeteer` and `cheerio` to open a browser, wait for the table to load, and then use a JQuery selector and pull the data. This is my code:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");


const main = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://paineis.cnj.jus.br/QvAJAXZfc/opendoc.htm?document=qvw_l%2FPainelCNJ.qvw&host=QVS%40neodimio03&anonymous=true&sheet=shPORT63Relatorios");
    await sleep(10*1000);
    const html = await page.content();
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    console.log($(".injected").text())

}

async function sleep(miliseconds) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, miliseconds));
}

main();
```

The problem is that the table I get as an answer is incomplete, with few lines and incomplete cells:

```
P63_CE_TRIBUNALCNJTribunalMagistradoMês/Ano Ref.CNJADHAILTON LACET CORREIA PORTO12/2018ADRIANA FRANCO MELO MACHADO02/202103/202104/2021ADRIANA LINS DE OLIVEIRA BEZERRA12/2018ADRIANO DA SILVA ARAUJO08/201909/201910/201911/201912/201901/202002/202003/202004/202005/202006/202007/202008/202009/202010/202011/202012/202001/202102/202103/202104/2021ALESSANDRA VARANDAS PAIVA MA...12/2018ALEXANDRE CHINI NETO09/201810/2018Subsídio (R$)Direitos Pessoais (1)Indenizações (2)Direitos Eventuais (3)Total de Rendimentos (4)Previdência Pública (5) (R$)Imposto de Renda (6) (R$)Descontos Diversos (7) (R$)Retenção por Teto Constitucional (8) (R$)Total de Descontos (9)Rendimento Líquido (10)Remuneração do órgão de origem (11) (R$)Diárias (12) (R$)0,000,000,00463,16463,160,000,000,000,000,00463,160,000,001.698,450,000,000,001.698,450,000,000,000,000,001.698,4533.689,110,003.639,540,0067.378,220,0071.017,760,00191,130,000,00191,1370.826,6333.689,110,003.639,540,000,000,003.639,540,00191,130,000,00191,133.448,4133.689,110,000,000,000,004.631,614.631,610,001.272,050,000,001.272,053.359,560,000,003.371,830,000,000,003.371,830,00150,970,000,00150,973.220,8632.004,710,005.323,940,000,000,005.323,940,00594,720,000,00594,724.729,2232.004,719.100,005.323,940,000,000,005.323,940,00594,720,000,00594,724.729,2232.004,717.700,005.323,940,000,000,005.323,940,00594,720,000,00594,724.729,2232.004,711.750,005.323,940,000,002.218,317.542,250,00618,290,000,00618,296.923,9632.004,719.100,005.323,940,000,002.661,977.985,910,00594,720,000,00594,727.391,1932.004,715.600,005.323,940,000,000,005.323,940,00594,720,000,00594,724.729,2232.004,714.550,005.323,940,000,000,005.323,940,00594,720,000,00594,724.729,2232.004,714.550,005.323,940,0032.004,710,0037.328,650,00594,720,000,00594,7236.733,9332.004,714.550,005.323,940,000,000,005.323,940,00594,720,000,00594,724.729,2232.004,710,005.323,940,004.158,850,009.482,790,00594,720,000,00594,728.888,0732.004,710,005.323,940,004.158,850,009.482,790,00673,560,000,00673,568.809,2332.004,710,005.323,940,004.158,85286,699.769,480,00673,560,000,00673,569.095,9232.004,710,005.323,940,000,000,005.323,940,00594,720,000,00594,724.729,2232.004,719.100,005.323,940,000,000,005.323,940,00594,720,000,00594,724.729,2232.004,714.550,005.323,940,000,000,005.323,940,00594,720,000,00594,724.729,2232.004,714.550,005.323,940,000,004.436,629.760,560,001.189,440,000,001.189,448.571,1232.004,714.550,005.323,940,000,002.661,977.985,910,00594,720,000,00594,727.391,1932.004,714.550,005.323,940,000,000,005.323,940,00594,720,000,00594,724.729,2232.004,714.550,005.323,940,000,000,005.323,940,00594,720,000,00594,724.729,2232.004,714.550,005.323,940,000,000,005.323,940,00594,720,000,00594,724.729,2232.004,714.550,000,000,000,004.631,614.631,610,001.272,050,000,001.272,053.359,560,000,003.127,300,000,000,003.127,300,00161,200,000,00161,202.966,1028.947,550,003.127,300,000,000,003.127,300,00114,300,000,00114,303.013,0028.947,5511.900,00
```

I tried several variations of the JQuery selector without success.

I read that I could communicate with QlikView using [enigmajs](https://github.com/qlik-oss/enigma.js/) and then make my request. However, it turns out that not even the most basic example in the documentation worked correctly on the site I'm using. Now I'm stuck.

How do I retrieve data from a table of a QlikView?

**EDIT:** Unfortunately, this specific URL doesn't appears to work for some countries outside Brazil. However, I think that any site with a QlikView table can be used as an example by the answer. The author of this (python) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66047767/the-right-api-scrape-method-to-extract-tables-from-a-qlikview-app) ran in the same problem with other site. Perhaps his url doesn't have the same access problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, the site currently gives "This page isn’t working. paineis.cnj.jus.br took too long to respond. HTTP ERROR 504", so it is hard to find out what may cause the incompleteness.

Comment: Can you try again another time? I just test and it works fine to me. Alternatively, one can enter this site https://www.cnj.jus.br/transparencia-cnj/remuneracao-dos-magistrados/ and then click on the link "painel do QlikView".

Comment: Unfortunately, both direct URL and clicking on  "painel do QlikView" produce the same error. Maybe some autorisation or region placement are needed.

Comment: the author of this question, also dealing with "open" information in Brazil, had the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66047767/the-right-api-scrape-method-to-extract-tables-from- a-qlikview-app The problem is essentially the same, but maybe this URL is accessible. I don't need a specific solution for my case, just a general one. Hence the answer can use any site with a QlikView table

Comment: The QlikView table linked in that other question doesn't seem to work outside Brazil, either. It just redirects to the home page. I suggest sharing a QlikView table from outside Brazil, or maybe sharing the raw HTML that you are loading into cheerio.

Answer (score 1):

First use `page.waitForSelector()` on any element that you know is visible when the content begin to appear. This is because page.content() will be triggered while the loader is still showing and maybe there's no -interesting- content to pick up.

Then you can notice that this website is implemented with lazy load inside the table that you want to reach, which means you need to scroll down the table multiple times to show all rows.

You can do something like that:

```
  async function autoScroll(page) {
    await page.evaluate(async () => {
      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var totalHeight = 0;
        var distance = 300;
        var timer = setInterval(() => {
          var scrollHeight = document.querySelector("yourScrollableElement").scrollHeight;
          document.querySelector("yourScrollableElement").scrollBy(0, distance);
          totalHeight += distance;

          if (totalHeight >= scrollHeight) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            resolve();
          }
        }, 250);
      });
    });
  }
```

*Change the timing and/or the distance (in pixels) for whatever number that fits into your load times and required scroll length.

Then you should be able to retrieve all data after a call like

```
await autoScroll(page);
```

such

```
await Promise.all([
    await page.goto(SITE_LINK),
    page.waitForSelector("MyTableIDorWhatever"),
    await autoScroll(page);
    // pick data
]);
```